# What is the most efficient way of analysing and identifing candle sticks?

Tags: sql, algorithm, graph-algorithm

A candlestick (chart), is a tool used for technical analysis of usually market movements. In a market or a specific equity:

```
open: opening price
close: closing price
high: highest price for the day
low: lowest price for the day
```

A candle is emplained by the figure below:
[image: Candlestick]

Now there are various patterns ( 2 or more candlesticks) that represent that the price may turn around (reversal) or continue (continuation). These patterns also give an indication to the most likely or usual direction after a certain pattern.

As an example this is a `bullish three inside up`, which indicated a bullish reversal:
[image: bullish three inside up]

That is a large down movement candle (large means the body is at least twice the length of the tails). Followed by a slight movement up whereby the entire candle can fit into the boy of the previous candle (known as `harami`: japanese word for pregnant). This is then followed by an up movement where the close falls above the 2nd close.

Note that in this case we want to make sure the candles are regular in shape (ie. `not hammers, hanging men, shooting star, inverted hammer, doji, spinning tops or marubozu`).
Which we can isolate by ensuring that open and closes are not equal, and that closes/opens are not equal to tops or bottoms.

The data set:

```
id      date        close       high        low         open
2284003 2014-07-14  25159.00    25391.00    25113.00    25074.00
2284864 2014-07-15  25227.00    25330.00    25044.00    25159.00
2285309 2014-07-16  25208.00    25463.00    25096.00    25227.00
2285310 2014-07-17  25365.00    25365.00    25031.00    25208.00
2287630 2014-07-18  25334.00    25383.00    24983.00    25365.00
```

Back to the algorithm for identification...

1. Identify the first candle (down body twice as long as length of tail)
   I will used SQL:

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (close < open) AND ((open - close) > 2 * ((high - open) + (low - close)))`

2. Now I'm sure this can be done in one query but I will assume the date, open and close for this candle is recorded in the variable `dt`, `op` and `cl` respectively. So we find the candle falling within the parameters.

`SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE date = DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND (close > open)
AND (high > close)
AND (low < open)
AND (high < op)
AND (low > cl)`

3. Finally we find the last candle.
   `SELECT * FROM tbl
   WHERE date = DATE_ADD(dt2, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   AND (close > open)
   AND (high > close)
   AND (low < open)
   AND (close > cl2)
   AND (close > cl)`.

Now I have a few efficiency problems:
1. I don't store the open and use the close of the previous day as the open which I need to change of course. 
2. On large data sets this could take lots of time.
3. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? (I am not bound by mySQL but I an used to it).

Comment: Storing only `close` is a way to keep the design normalized.  As it's unlikely to change (often), you could reasonably use a derived column, though.  I think we need to see your expected output data.  Why _can't_ the low/high be equal to the open/close?  Why does it have to be at least a specified amount greater?  What RDBMS are you using - I have a feeling good solutions will need db-specific behavior (this sounds like a job for windowing functions, which aren't present on all dbs).

Comment: I'm using `MySQL Server`. Of course the storing of open would introduce duplicates. Regarding the candles, if the highs and lows are equal to the close or high these are more significant candles (doji/marubozu etc) and when these candles are in the specific pattern the open must equal the high, etc. Back to the algorithm, I think that this is the most efficient method of finding the pattern...currently there are 2200000 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to itself

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl t1 
     join tbl t2 ON (t1.date=DATE_ADD(t2.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
WHERE
  t1.date>=start_date
and t1.date<end_date
-- plus all the candle restrictions here  --
```

You can compare all the close/open/high/low of t1 with next date's values from t2

Comment: This is my exact syntax: `SELECT * FROM dly t1
JOIN dly t2 ON (t1.dt = DATE_ADD(t2.dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
WHERE t1.nms_id = 2620
AND t2.nms_id = 2620;` is it possible to only show the close from t2 and alias to open?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you asked